# How does one fit a binding model with 2 variables in the xdata spot?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

What I have so far, thanks to many who have helped:

```
#defining function that applies the binding model to the data
def binding_model(xdata, Vcell, Ka, n, dH):
    #packaging Mt and Xt into one object to abide by curve_fit rules
    #avoiding 'divide by 0' errors by truncating lists
    Mt[1:] = xdata[0]
    Xt[1:] = xdata[1]
    #breaking up the equation for simplicity
    a = n*Mt*dH*Vcell/2
    b = 1+(Xt/(Mt*n))
    c = 1/(n*Ka*Mt)
    d = 1+(Xt/(n*Mt))+(1/(n*Ka*Mt))
    e = 4*Xt/(Mt*n)
    #combining variables into the whole equation
    return a*(b+c)-(d**2-e**.5)

#fitting molar enthalpy vs. molar ratio data with the binding model
initial_Vcell = 0
initial_Ka = 0
initial_n = 0
initial_dH = 0
initial_paramaters = np.array([initial_Vcell, initial_Ka, initial_n,
                               initial_dH])
xdata = zip(Mt, Xt)
xdata = np.array(xdata)
parameters, cov = curve_fit(binding_model, xdata, peak_areas, p0=
                            initial_paramaters)
Vcell = parameters[0]
Ka = parameters[1]
n = parameters[2]
dH = parameters[3]
Ffit = binding_model(xdata, Vcell, Ka, n, dH)
```

returns:

```
  File "mygroatitc.py", line 164, in binding_model
    Mt[1:] = xdata[0]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (40)
```

Does anyone have experience using curve-fit or zipping variables to find my error?

Vcell is an integer, Mt and Xt are equally-sized arrays, peak_areas (equally-sized array to Mt or Xt) is my ydata in the curve_fit function.

Comment: I believe the problem is using xdata = zip(Mt, Xt). Here this only gives two values.

Whereas peak_areas which is your y variable has 40 values.

Comment: did it work, the solution?

Comment: was the solution the one given by Matt, the one you accepted?

Comment: Yes, ravel() was the solution, in addition to your advice to annul the zip() function I also had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

binding_model() must return a 1d numpy array.  Use:

```
 residual = a*(b+c)-(d**2-e**.5)
 return residual.ravel()
```

Comment: Sorry, that still returns the same error. I'll read up on ravel on numpy's site to see if I can tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see.  You hadn't actually specified what Mt or Xt are.  We're these defined above?   In your bind_model() function you're reassigning to these global variables (and each iteration).  Is that really what you want?

If you're having trouble with data layout with curve_fit(), I  highly recommend using leastsq() instead -- curve_fit() is just a wrapper around leastsq() anyway.   With leastsq(), the objective function takes the array of parameters as the first arguments, can take additional arguments (this is where you pass in the "y" data), and returns the 1-d array to be minimized in the least-squares sense.  If you're pull apart multi-dimensional arrays into separately named arrays just to fit curve_fit()s ideas, it might just be easier to use leastsq() and pass in Mt, Xt to the objective function.

Comment: Mt and Xt are both arrays of the same size; both are global variables I calculated with a previous function and useful in calculating others. Your suggestion to use ravel(), with @Srivatsan 's advice to annul the zip(Mt, Xt) function I previously had were able to answer my question. I'm still working to tweak the curve_fit function to better calculate thermodynamic values, but your advice may to use leastsq() may be a better idea. I will look into it, thank you!